# Code not clear from a movie . Is this legal?

Tags: c++, syntax

Saw this in a movie(Night Hunter 2019) and I never saw a for-statement written this way (assuming this is C++). Is this syntax legal? What is it saying?

(Timestamp 46:30 minutes)

[image]

The code I'm referring to is, specifically `HUNTER71`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < group_info->nblocks; HUNTER71 i++)
    free_page((unsigned long)group_info->blocks[i]);
```

Comment: `HUNTER71` could be a macro that expands to nothing, for example; as in `#define HUNTER71`. Basically, there are ways to add code around these lines to make them compile; and also ways to make them fail to compile. It's a movie; real bombs don't typically have blinking lights on them, either.

Comment: I've edited your question to include what I can only guess is the code you're asking about, but if it's wrong please [edit] your question further.

Comment: maybe someone copy-pasted their password by accident

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you are referring to the following snippet:

```
for (int i = 0; i < group_info->nblocks; HUNTER71 i++)
    free_page((unsigned long)group_info->blocks[i]);
```

Yes, this is valid C++; however, it could just as easily be C or a different language altogether. I'll continue as if it's C++

So it's valid, but what could it do? Well as Igor points out in the comments, it could just be a macro that does nothing:

```
#define HUNTER71
for (int i = 0; i < group_info->nblocks; HUNTER71 i++)
    free_page((unsigned long)group_info->blocks[i]);
```

Furthermore, `HUNTER71` could actually do some logic, such as increment a variable, or even print how many times we've looped:

```
#define HUNTER71 std::cout << i,
for (int i = 0; i < group_info->nblocks; HUNTER71 i++)
    free_page((unsigned long)group_info->blocks[i]);
```

It's not clear what it could be doing, but it's not uncommon for `for` statements to do additional logic in the `for` itself.